# Cancelling AsyncRelayCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, cancellationtokensource, windows-community-toolkit

This is WPF (.NET Framework 4.8). I need to supply two `<Button>`s in the UI to start and stop a long-running background process. The start button should initially be enabled and will get disabled once the command is issued (to avoid a second click). The stop button will be disabled initially and will get enabled once the process starts running.

I'm using `AsyncRelayCommand` supplied in [Windows Community Toolkit's MVVM library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/introduction). The buttons bind to their VM through normal XAML binding. The underlying commands look like this:

```
private AsyncRelayCommand _StartPumpingCommand;
public AsyncRelayCommand StartPumpingCommand
{
  get
  {
    _StartPumpingCommand ??= new AsyncRelayCommand(async (CancellationToken token) =>
      {
        dispatcher.Invoke(() => _CancelPumpingCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged());
        await SomeTask(token);
      },
      () => {
        /* SomeTask is not running and a cancellation has not been requested  */
        return !_StartPumpingCommand.IsRunning && !_StartPumpingCommand.IsCancellationRequested;
      });

    return _StartPumpingCommand;
  }
}


private RelayCommand _CancelPumpingCommand;
public RelayCommand CancelPumpingCommand
{
  get
  {
    _CancelPumpingCommand ??= new RelayCommand(() =>
      {
        if(_StartPumpingCommand?.IsRunning??false)
          _StartPumpingCommand.Cancel();
      },
      () => _StartPumpingCommand?.IsRunning??false);

    return _CancelPumpingCommand;
  }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is my implementation of the two commands correct?
2. Does `AsyncRelayCommand` internally contain `CancellationTokenSource` magic, or do I need to create one in the VM class myself and use it in the two commands above?
3. How do I communicate the completion of `StartPumpingCommand` to the `CancelPumpingCommand`, so that the buttons in the UI get enabled/disabled accordingly? Are we supposed to call `CancelPumpingCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged()` after `SomeTask()` returns? How will it behave since `CancelPumpingCommand` uses `StartPumpingCommand.IsRunning` property to decide its availability, and `StartPumpingCommand` would still be running, right?

Comment: Have you looked at the interface IAsyncRelayCommand? I guess not. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/communitytoolkit.mvvm.input.IAsyncRelayCommand?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0

There is a cancel method. You will need code in your task to actually do any cancellation just as you would in any task. That task is passed in as a parameter when you new up your command.

Comment: @Andy: Thanks. I know about `Cancel()` and it is already being used in my code above. Did u just read the question title? Please read my questions.

Comment: Thanks. Just figured out the proper way. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. Here is the correct way of doing async commands in Community Toolkit in case it helps someone:

```
private AsyncRelayCommand _StartPumpingCommand;
public AsyncRelayCommand StartPumpingCommand
{
  get
  {
    _StartPumpingCommand ??= new AsyncRelayCommand(async (CancellationToken token) =>
      {
        try
        {
          await Task.Run(() => SomeTask(token), token);
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException)
        {
          //do whatever u want to do in case of task cancellation
        }
      },
      () => !_StartPumpingCommand.IsRunning);

    return _StartPumpingCommand;
  }
}

private ICommand _CancelPumpingCommand;
public ICommand CancelPumpingCommand
{
  get
  {
    _CancelPumpingCommand ??= StartPumpingCommand.CreateCancelCommand();
    return _CancelPumpingCommand;
  }
}

private async Task SomeTask(CancellationToken token)
{
  //I'm using "await foreach" which requires C# 8 and an Nuget
  //package named `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces` when targeting
  //.NET Framework. You may use some other way of creating a 
  //Task here.
  await foreach(...)
  { 
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    //do stuff
  }
}
```

This works perfectly correctly. My UI is totally responsive (no deadlocks) and I can cancel and restart the task any number of times. This suggests that `AsyncRelayCommand` internally contains task cancellation magic and needs nothing more than awaitable method to work.

Comment: Works prefectly in .NET MAUI with CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.

Answer (score 4):

Here is `[RelayCommand(IncludeCancelCommand = true)]` attribute.

See https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/issues/118 for details.

For example, this

```cs
[RelayCommand(IncludeCancelCommand = true)]
private Task StartPumpingAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    // Command body.
}
```

should create two commands: `StartPumpingCommand` and `StartPumpingCancelCommand`. For custom implementation you may see `IncludeCancelCommand` or `IAsyncRelayCommand.CreateCancelCommand` extension.

P.S. I don't know if this functionalities are officially documented, but Windows Community Toolkit MVVM has docstrings.